# Obtener el valor de una celda al hacer clic según la columna 0 de un QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, python-3.7, pyqt

Se busca que al hacer clic en una fila, se obtenga el valor que se encuentra en el row según la columna 0, por ejemplo, que cada vez que se haga clic en una fila (por ejemplo, la fila 1) se obtenga el valor correspondiente al row 1 de la columna 0, y así sucesivamente; el objeto LISTACLIENTES (Que es un QTableWidget) se llena a partir de una tabla Clientes de una base de datos SQLITE.

Estas son las propiedades de la LISTACLIENTES:

```
self.LISTACLIENTES = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.CUADROBAJAEMPLEADOS_3)
    self.LISTACLIENTES.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 1041, 301))
    self.LISTACLIENTES.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
    self.LISTACLIENTES.setShowGrid(True)
    self.LISTACLIENTES.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
    self.LISTACLIENTES.setObjectName("LISTACLIENTES")
    self.LISTACLIENTES.setColumnCount(12)
    self.LISTACLIENTES.setRowCount(0)
    self.LISTACLIENTES.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
    self.LISTACLIENTES.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
    self.LISTACLIENTES.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
    header = ["Id.","Nombre","Direccion","CP","Telefono","Correo", "Mascota","Tipo de Mascota","Raza","Peso (en Kg)","Servicio 1","Servicio 2"]
    self.LISTACLIENTES.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header)
    self.LISTACLIENTES.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QTableView.SelectRows
```

y este es el código que se tiene actualmente, mismo que llena el objeto LISTACLIENTES a partir de la tabla Clientes:

```
self.LISTACLIENTES.setRowCount(0)
    CargarDatos = "SELECT * FROM Clientes"
    DatosClientes = conn.execute(CargarDatos)
    for row_number, row_data in enumerate (DatosClientes):
        self.LISTACLIENTES.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number, data in enumerate (row_data):
            self.LISTACLIENTES.setItem(row_number, column_number,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

    ids = str(self.LISTACLIENTES.item(row_number,0).text())
    self.BAJAIDCLIENTEDATOS.setPlainText(ids)
```

Con el código que se tiene actualmente, solo se obtiene el valor de la última fila con la columna 0, mismo que se inserta en un QPlainText de solo lectura.
Lo que se busca es que el valor sea dinámico a partir de hacer clic en el row correspondiente.

Así es como se ve la LISTACLIENTES actualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar la señal `itemSelectionChanged` del `QTableWidget` y en el slot obtener la fila seleccionada y a partir de ella el texto del item de la columna 1. Solo te queda asignar dicho texto al `QPlainText`.

Dejo un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ventana(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.baja_id = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.baja_id.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 480, 211, 41))
        self.baja_id.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lista_clientes = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.lista_clientes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(45, 41, 701, 371))
        self.lista_clientes.setColumnCount(2)
        self.lista_clientes.setRowCount(2)

        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.lista_clientes.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.lista_clientes.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.lista_clientes.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.lista_clientes.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.lista_clientes.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.lista_clientes.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.lista_clientes.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.lista_clientes.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = self.lista_clientes.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText("1")
        item = self.lista_clientes.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText("2")
        item = self.lista_clientes.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText("Id.")
        item = self.lista_clientes.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText("Nombre")
        item = self.lista_clientes.item(0, 0)
        item.setText("1")
        item = self.lista_clientes.item(0, 1)
        item.setText("Luís Enrique")
        item = self.lista_clientes.item(1, 0)
        item.setText("2")
        item = self.lista_clientes.item(1, 1)
        item.setText("Luciana Altamira")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 480, 81, 41))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("Ide. Cliente")

        self.lista_clientes.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.lista_clientes.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.on_selec_change)



    @QtCore.pyqtSlot() 
    def on_selec_change(self):
        row = self.lista_clientes.currentRow()
        item = self.lista_clientes.item(row, 0)
        if item is not None:
            self.baja_id.setPlainText(item.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = Ventana()
    ventana.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En primera instancia esta solución funciona, sin embargo, una vez que se regresa a la LISTACLIENTES, se obtiene en consola el siguiente error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.
Esto ocurre siempre al volver a ingresar a la LISTACLIENTES.

Comment: @LuisTovar efectivamente eso puede pasar si por cualquier razón se deselecciona toda fila de la tabla. He editado la respuesta para tenerlo en cuenta, ahora no debería pasar. Otra forma es comprobar que `row` no sea un valor negativo, si lo es significa que no hay fila seleccionada.